# Required fields are missing (Bulk API)

Tags: api, upsert, bulk, required

I'm trying to upsert a new Contact record using the Bulk API and it's returning the following error:

```
[{"errors"=>
        [{"fields"=>["DDA_External_Id__c"],
          "message"=>["Required fields are missing: [DDA_External_Id__c]"],
          "statusCode"=>["REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING"]}],
       "success"=>["false"],
       "created"=>["true"]}]
```

The error seems trivial but I don't know why am I getting it since I do provide such required field:

```
=> [{"DDA_External_Id__c"=>"x",
  "AccountId"=>"x",
  "FirstName"=>"x",
  "LastName"=>"x",
  "Email"=>"x"}]
```

Comment: did u check if the value is set for all of the records in ur request ?

Comment: Yep, I'm running it with a single record at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the error came from the AccountContactRelation object, not Contact.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/58008)

Comment: How does it not provide an answer to my question ?

Comment: Because in review the context is not there. The answer looks like a comment. While you may feel it is an answer it is vague enough to not be very useful thus why it looks like a comment during review

Comment: I actually agree that there is not enough context to really qualify this as an answer. Imagine if you were someone else looking at this post. It would be pretty unlikely to help you. Can you add more detail?